# Prepopulate additional instances of a multivalue text field based on another existing text field?

Tags: 8, forms

Consider the following (newly created) form:

- `field_country` (option select)
- `field_phonenumber` number (multivalue text field)

When the user chooses from field_country, then the user can add unlimited instances of `field_phonenumber` fields, which should be pre-populated with the selected country code.

I was able to prepopulate the first instance of `field_phonenumber` with AJAX, but not the additional instances.

`$form_state->getValue(field_country)` was empty for the additional instances of `field_phonenumber`.

Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Edit: the code I tried so far:

```
function testmodule_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  $handlers = $entity_types['node']->get('handlers');
  $handlers['form']['edit']     = 
    'Drupal\testmodule\Form\CompanyContactInfoForm';
  $handlers['form']['default']  = 
    'Drupal\testmodule\Form\CompanyContactInfoForm';
  $entity_types['node']->set('handlers', $handlers);
}
```

```
namespace Drupal\testmodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeForm;

/**
 * @ingroup testmodule
 */
class CompanyContactInfoForm extends NodeForm {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);

    $form['#attributes']['id'] = 'form-fixed-id';

    $form['field_country']["widget"]['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => '::addCountryCode',
      'wrapper' => $form['#attributes']['id'],
      'event' => 'change',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'progress' => ['type' => 'throbber', 'message' => t('Adding country calling code..')],
    );

    return $form;
  }

  public function addCountryCode (array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    foreach (array_keys($form['field_phonenumber']['widget']) as $key) {
        if (is_numeric($key)) {
            $form['field_phonenumber']['widget'][$key]['value']['#value'] = static::getCountryCode($form_state->getValue('field_country')[0]['value']);
        }
    }
    return $form;
  }

  public static function getCountryCode ($country) {
    $codes = array(
        "Belgium"     => "+32",
        "France"      => "+33",
        "Greece"      => "+30"
    );
    return $codes[$country];
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post what have you tried so far, how did you repopulate the first item?

Comment: @berramou I added the code.